# How to do ThenFetch in Hql and How do you break up many joins in nhibernate linq?

Tags: nhibernate

I have 2 questions

1. How do you do a then fetch in hql?

like in linq it would be

```
var allRecords = session.Query<Table1P>().FetchMany(x => x.Table2).ThenFetchMany(x => x.Table5s);
```

1. How to break up a query when you have too many joins.

   var allRecords = session.Query().FetchMany(x => x.Table2).FetchMany(x => x.Table3).FetchMany(x => x.Table4).FetchMany(x => x.Table6).ToList();

how could I break this up so that it does not do it all in one go? I want to eager load but don't want to load it all in one go. I rather try to break it up.

> it is often more efficient to perform several separate queries instead
>   of a single query with several joins in it.

http://nhprof.com/Learn/Alerts/TooManyJoins

Comment: Point 2 - Yeah, Ayende is right. To me it seems like the problem of the egg and the chicken: you can't have both! Are proxies and lazy load a viable way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use futures. Here is an example: http://ayende.com/blog/4367/eagerly-loading-entity-associations-efficiently-with-nhibernate